# Dates Overlapping cases for Leave System

Tags: sql-server

I'm making date overlapping cases in SQL Server where I want to check a person applying for leave should get to know if 2 or more persons have already applied for leave for the those dates. Now the catch is, suppose 2 people have already taken leave as:

Person 1: 1st Feb 2020 to 2nd Feb 2020

Person 2: 1st Feb 2020 to 5th Feb 2020

Now the person 3 applying leave for 1st Feb 2020 to 5th Feb 2020 should get the leave for 3rd Feb 2020 to 5th Feb 2020.

There can be much more cases to it. How to achieve it?

So far I have made a stored procedure which returns the total no is leave applied during a period.

Eg: if my table have a record for 1st Feb to 1st Feb it will return the total no of people who have applied to those specific dates. It returns null leave applied for 1st Feb to 2nd Feb.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[check_leave_application](
@from_date date,
@to_date date
)
as
begin
declare @total_leaves_applied int
declare @id_count int

if @from_date = @to_date
begin

select @total_leaves_applied=count(id) from leaveRequest where current_status in (0,1) and 
((cast(FromDate as date) >= @from_date and (cast(FromDate as date)<=@to_date))
or (cast(ToDate as date) between @from_date and @to_date))
end
select @total_leaves_applied as total_leaves_applied

end
```

**Table Structure:**

```
id  FromDate    ToDate            request_date        current_status    
3   2020-01-22  2020-01-23    2020-01-22 15:41:07.943            0  
3   2020-01-22  2020-01-23    2020-01-22 16:01:54.787            0
```

Comment: putting tags in the question is discouraged as its un-necessary.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete working sample script? something that creates the table, populates it with some sample data, and then the query. It's not clear what datatypes ToDate and FromDate are, although I suspect they are strings (WHY?)... +

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it might be a good starting point. Using Common Table Expressions (CTE), SQL Server allows you to generate a sequence of data.
You can use this to generate a table of dates and then join your Employee Leave table to it, allowing you to `COUNT` how many employees took leave for a given day. Knowing that number each day, you then simply take the `MAX` to find out if any day has been booked more than twice:

```
-- Just creating a temp table to simulate your data
SELECT *
INTO #EmployeeLeave
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, '2020-01-22' AS FromDate, '2020-01-23' AS ToDate, '2020-01-22 15:41:07.943' AS request_date, 0 AS current_status UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, '2020-01-22' AS FromDate, '2020-01-23' AS ToDate, '2020-01-22 16:01:54.787' AS request_date, 0 AS current_status UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, '2020-01-03' AS FromDate, '2020-01-07' AS ToDate, '2020-01-03 12:00:00.000' AS request_date, 0 AS current_status UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS id, '2020-01-05' AS FromDate, '2020-01-09' AS ToDate, '2020-01-03 12:00:00.000' AS request_date, 0 AS current_status UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id, '2020-01-06' AS FromDate, '2020-01-06' AS ToDate, '2020-01-03 12:00:00.000' AS request_date, 0 AS current_status UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS id, '2020-01-01' AS FromDate, '2020-01-02' AS ToDate, '2020-01-03 12:00:00.000' AS request_date, 0 AS current_status UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS id, '2020-01-01' AS FromDate, '2020-01-01' AS ToDate, '2020-01-03 12:00:00.000' AS request_date, 0 AS current_status
) A

-- Try book leave from 1st to 3rd of January
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '2020-01-01'
DECLARE @ToDate DATE = '2020-01-03';

-- Generate a Dates table
WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT [Date] = @FromDate
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
    FROM Dates
    WHERE [Date] < @ToDate
)

-- Use dates table to get the maximum number of people that have booked leave on a particular day within @FromDate and @ToDate
SELECT
    MAX(EmployeesBookedLeave) AS HighestBookedDayInInterval
FROM (
    -- For each day, get number of Leave records that have been joined
    SELECT
    Date, COUNT(*) AS EmployeesBookedLeave
    FROM Dates D
    JOIN #EmployeeLeave E
        -- join Leave records that contain each Date
        ON D.Date BETWEEN E.FromDate AND E.ToDate
    GROUP BY Date
) A

-- Clean up
DROP TABLE #EmployeeLeave
```

Now if HighestBookedDayInInterval is > 2, the employee cannot book that day.

Comment: Thanks mate, although i found a partial solution by making some cases but i'll definitely try this one as well.